# How to import a directory into a single file component

Tags: vue.js

I am using a photo gallery component in my project. It requires a path to the folder containing the images. I am unable to find a way to do this. I have created an `img` directory inside of `assets`, and I'm using the standard Vue CLI 3 scaffolding. I'm able to use a `require('path/to/file/name.png')`, but what I need is to be able to bring the whole folder in. I'm unable to figure out a way to do this. I even tried placing the images in a folder inside of `public`, but no luck.

My structure looks like this:

```
project/public/img
project/src/assets/img/
project/src/components/
```

I need to get the `project/src/assets/img` path into a component inside of `project/src/components/componentName.vue`.

I should also mention that I want to be able to access this directory from the `script` tag, not the `template` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
const requireModule = require.context('../assets/img.',false,/\.png$/)
const images = {}

requireModule.keys().forEach(filename => 
{
    const imageName = fileName.replace(/(\.\/|\.png)/g, '');
    images[imageName] = requireModule(fileName)

    OR

    images[imageName] = 
    {
        namespaced: true,
        ...requireModule(fileName)
    }
});

export default images;
```

Then you can import this file

```
import photos from 'imagesObject.js'

for (let key in photos) // do whatever you want with the image
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer IVO. That solution did work, but I found another that I wanted to share here for anyone else having a similar problem. The issue I was having was incorrectly referencing the public folder using a relative path instead of BASE_URL. Based on this...
[The public Folder Vue CLI Documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#url-transform-rules)

I created a directory inside of /public then referenced it using process.env.BASE_URL. This solved the problem. Here are the relevant snippets:
Javascript:

```
data () {
        return {
            thumbnailDir : process.env.BASE_URL + 'portfolio/'
        }
```

Template:

```
<transition-group name="thumbnailfade" tag="div">
        <img v-for="thumb in filteredImages"
             :key="thumb.id"
             @click="showLightbox(thumb.name)"
             :src="thumbnailDir + thumb.name"
             :alt="thumb.alt"
             :title="thumb.alt"/>
    </transition-group>

    <lightbox id="mylightbox"
              ref="lightbox"
              :images="images"
              :directory="thumbnailDir"
              :filter="galleryFilter"
              :timeoutDuration="5000"
    />
```